# replace entire variable line using partially matched regex in javascript from an external file

Tags: javascript

I've two files. Lets call them *first.js* and *second.js*.
Since second.js is called by html, I cant use `require`. So I am trying to modify a parameter in *second.js* from *first.js*.

First is running on a node.js server. I need to replace/update  ipAddress variable value from second.js every-time I run first.js

So in *first.js* , I am trying to use external `replace`module (any other way is ok as well).

First I open external file (second.js) from first.js, then search for
`var ipaddress = "192.168.0.10"`

This ip address changes everytime. So I am trying to search on `var ipaddress` and need to to replace it with variable `ipaddr`.

Here is what I have so far.

Partial contents of *first.js*.

```
function replaceIP(ipaddress){
    var replace = require("replace");
    replace({
        regex: "^var ipAddress.*$",
        replacement: "var ipAddress = " + ipaddr,
        paths: ['./second.js'],
        recursive: false,
        silent: false,
        });
}
```

This is not working.

If I just use hardcoded value for iPAddress , like
`var ipAddress = 'XXXX';`
And the replace 'XXXX'. Its working fine.

So I know it has to be with RegEx and not 'Replace' Module.

**EDIT:**
Also problem is second.js ipAddress variable will store different value for every login session , Hence I cant grab onto entire string since I dont know what it will be, Hence I am grabbing onto starting portion (`^var ipAddress`) of declaration statement.

e.g first login :   `var ipAddress = '192.168.0.10';`
second login session: `var ipAddress = '192.168.0.12';`
third login session: `var ipAddress = '192.168.0.18';`

and so on.

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495506/python-find-pattern-and-replace-entire-line) that replaces entire line in `python` based on partial match of string.
Can I do something like this in `javascript`?

Any ideas?

PS: I looked at few other Q & A on SO, and it does not seem to address the issue.
Thanks.

Comment: first.js is running on the server? The question is really confusing. Can you explain what you need to do instead?

Comment: First is running on a node.js server. I need to replace/update  ipAddress  variable value from second.js every-time I run first.js

Comment: Why are you trying to replace variable values in another script through regex? Why not just grab whatever it is that is done in first.js to get the ip address, and use it in second.js to set the variable?

Comment: IP Address is DHCP based. Everytime I login it will change. Also I cant grab it in second.js since its called by html. I will have to use modules in second.js that causes problem on html load. Easiest way is to update second.js ipAddress from first.js if I can figure out proper regex since second.js is called after first.js is loaded. First.js detects ipAddress. (Both first and second js  are run on same machine).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve above using `shell.js` which offers straigt-forward unix like shell commands across platform. Really impressed with its ease of use.

I guess the key was `searchPattern = /^.*var ipAddr =.*$/;`

```
function replaceIP(ipAddr) {
    var shell = require("shelljs");
    var searchPattern = /^.*var ipAddr =.*$/;
    var replacePattern = "var ipAddr = '" + ipAddr + "';";
    var cwd = shell.pwd().stdout;
    var file = cwd + '/second.js';
    shell.sed('-i', searchPattern, replacePattern, file);
    console.log("replacing " + ipAddr + " in file " + file);
}
```

Then call using,
`replaceIP(ipAddr)`